# How to use user input as a while loop condition

Tags: bash, shell, test, read, control-flow

I can do this in bash:

```
while read -n1 -r -p "choose [y]es|[n]o"
do
    if [[ $REPLY == q ]];
    then
        break;
    else
        #whatever
    fi
done
```

which works but seems a bit redundant, can i do something like this instead?

```
while [[ `read -n1 -r -p "choose [y]es|[n]o"` != q ]]
do
    #whatever
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use the return code of `read` (it's zero if it gets valid, nonempty input), and you can't use its output (`read` doesn't print anything). But you can put multiple commands in the condition part of a while loop. The condition of a while loop can be as complex a command as you like.

```
while IFS= read -n1 -r -p "choose [y]es|[n]o" && [[ $REPLY != q ]]; do
  case $REPLY in
    y) echo "Yes";;
    n) echo "No";;
    *) echo "What?";;
  esac
done
```

(This exits the loop if the input is `q` or if an end-of-file condition is detected.)

Comment: might also just use `while read REPLY ; do ` and add the `case $REPLY in ; q) break ;; ` (or `exit`) that way `REPLY` is not evaluated twice.

Answer (score -1):

> Implementation with a simple read and break

```
while read release; do
 if [ "$release" == "07" ]; then
        break
 else
        echo "Is that current release? e.g: 05. Try again!"
        continue
 fi
done
```

Comment: This seems to reproduce exactly the kind of code that the user in the question wanted to avoid. They asked whether it was possible to move the condition of the  `if` shatement (your `"$release" == "07"`) into the `while` loop condition.