# Shell script : add "exit by typing q" to while do case already dependent on an if

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm writing a shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1;
sp="/-\|";
no_config=true;
echo "type \"continue\" to exit this while loop";
echo "if you feel the conditions for continuing sucessfully have been met... ";
while $no_config;
do printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}";
[[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false;
sleep 1;
done;
# do more stuff
```

I'd like to now add a user-provoked exit out of the loop as well.

this seems complicated.

at first I found this and my hopes were up :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228152/228658
but as it turns out the read command halts execution.

I don't want that. I want something like man pages where if at any time you hit "q" it exits but it isn't halting the ability to scroll up and down. it is waiting for input in the background discreetly.

how would I accomplish that in a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to inform the user to press `Ctrl-C` to exit the loop, which would issue the `SIGINT` signal and end the script.

If you want to do something else before ending the script, you can trap the signal:

```
cleanup() {
  # ...
  exit 0
}
trap 'cleanup' INT
```

---

Alternatively, you can run one of them in a subshell, making sure that when one of the shells exits, the other is killed as well. This way you can have one of them blocked for input while the other does the other checks.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
sp="/-\|"
no_config=true
echo "type \"continue\" to exit this while loop if you feel the conditions for continuing sucessfully have been met... "
(
while $no_config
do 
  printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
  [[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false
  sleep 1
done
kill $$
) &
child_pid=$!

while $no_config
do
  read -r typed_continue
  [[ "$typed_continue" = "continue" ]] && no_config=false
  sleep 1
done
kill $child_pid
```

Comment: wow subshell actually doesn't open another terminal. what is this back magic? also why `set -eu` and why `/usr/bin/env bash` I did not use those two?

Comment: Those changes are optional, I've reverted them. I also added another alternative if you feel the subshell solution is too complex for your needs.

Comment: no it acutally works. I don't understand how but it accomplishes what I want, thanks! is it POSIX?

Comment: Subshells are POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12, basically they are sub processes that do their own parallel processing. You can read more about it here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: I'm having trouble having this code inline of a terminal tab, by which I mean the whole set of commands are between quotes and each line has a `;` at the end. this worked file for the while loop above but the parentheses are causing issues. what would be the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Bash does not lend itself nicely to such controls.

However there can be some ways to obtain something workable.

From the simplest to the most complex, here are some:

**Type Ctrl+C to exit**

You can install a `trap` for Ctrl+C (handled by catching the signal INT) to make it set your `no_config` value to `false` so that your `while` loop quits on Ctrl+C:

```bash
i=1
sp='/-\|'
no_config=true
echo "type Ctrl+C to exit this while loop"
echo "if you feel the conditions for continuing successfully have been met... ";
trap 'no_config=false' INT
while $no_config; do
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    [[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false
    sleep 1
done
trap 'trap - INT; kill -INT $$' INT
echo "do more stuff"
```

(If you run the above code from an interactive shell **remember** to surround the whole code with a leading `(` and a trailing `)` so that your shell won't be polluted by what the code does.)

Note that the `while` loop will actually be interrupted only when all commands inside the loop have completed, because the test on `$no_config` occurs only at the `while`. You may or may not want this behavior depending on what you do inside the loop. In your example case the only true “slow” operation is the explicit `sleep 1`, so an abrupt interruption shouldn’t be necessary, but if you do want to interrupt the loop no-matter-what then the easiest addendum is by using one sub-shell to be killable as a whole. Like this:

```bash
trap 'kill $!' INT
(
i=1
sp='/-\|'
no_config=true
echo "type Ctrl+C to exit this while loop"
echo "if you feel the conditions for continuing successfully have been met... ";
while $no_config; do
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    [[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false
    sleep 1
done
) &
wait
trap 'trap - INT; kill -INT $$' INT
echo "do more stuff"
```

Here we set a `trap` for INT (Ctrl+C) which kills the sub-shell, so that the `wait` proceeds to the “do more stuff” part.

Note however that, by doing this way, variables set within the loop do not propagate to the "do more stuff" part. To work around this you need some ancillary communication like a temporary file or named-FIFO.

---

**Type 'q' to exit**

An alternative to the above that would allow you to use any character to quit (thus also leaving Ctrl+C to its regular operation) might be by embedding a non-blocking `read` (available on Bash v4+) within the loop. This also requires some ancillary preparations for terminal settings. The whole thing might be like this:

```bash
term_settings="$(stty -g)"
trap 'stty "${term_settings}"' EXIT
i=1
sp='/-\|'
no_config=true
echo "type exactly \"q\" to exit this while loop"
echo "if you feel the conditions for continuing successfully have been met... ";
stty -icanon -echo
while $no_config; do
    while read -t 0 && read -rN 1 ; do [ "${REPLY}" = q ] && break 2 || true; done
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    [[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false
    sleep 1
done
stty "${term_settings}"
echo "do more stuff"
```

Here we first save the terminal’s current settings to restore them later and on EXIT, then disable displaying of typed character (`-echo`) and line-oriented keyboard input (`-icanon`). Within the `while` loop we use `read -t 0` (non-blocking `read`) to check for presence of typed characters, in which case we read them all one by one (`-N 1`) to test whether any one of them is `q` to quit the loop.

This adds a bit of computational overhead due to the `read -t 0` done at each iteration of your `while` loop. In your example case the overhead is negligible.

---

If you wish an abruptly interruptible loop with a `type q to quit`, a different approach is necessary, and things get much more complicated because you have to resort to running the interruptible part of your code in background while waiting on a `read` in a foreground code, and this also requires a way to unblock the `read` when the background code completes regularly.

Obtaining this requires a lot of stretching Bash’s abilities, for instance by:

1. enclosing the interruptible part of your code in a background sub-shell on its own, a bit like we’ve done earlier but with additional cares taken
2. simulating a Ctrl+C from the background sub-shell to the foreground `read`.

This also means that it won't be possible to pass variables from the `while` loop to the "do more stuff" part, just like we said earlier (an ancillary communication would need to be set up on purpose).

An example might be like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

term_settings="$(stty -g)"
(
trap 'stty "${term_settings}"' EXIT
_keyboard_waiter=$BASHPID
(
i=1
sp='/-\|'
no_config=true
echo "type exactly \"q\" to exit this while loop"
echo "if you feel the conditions for continuing successfully have been met... ";
while $no_config; do
    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    [[ ! $(pidof SupremeCommande) && -f ~/My\ Documents/newfile ]] && no_config=false
    sleep 1
done
kill -INT $_keyboard_waiter
) &
while read -rsN 1 && ! [ "${REPLY}" = q ] ; do :; done
{ kill $! && wait; } 2>/dev/null
)
echo "do more stuff"
```

Here we have:

- better used the whole thing through a script file, due to the required handling of signals
- terminal settings saved at the beginning to restore them later on EXIT, which is necessary for when `read` gets interrupted
- one sub-shell run in foreground, responsible for waiting input from keyboard
- one sub-sub-shell run in background (&) for the interruptible part of the code
- use of `kill -INT` by the background sub-shell to interrupt the `read`'s sub-shell. This simulates Ctrl+C for that sub-shell, which is handled by Bash
- an option-ed `read` to not show typed characters (`-s`) while also waiting/accepting just one character regardless of newlines (`-N 1`), plus the common `-r` to not interpret backslashes as escape character
- a simple “kill&wait” to the background sub-shell for when ‘q’ is indeed typed

Comment: what a very complete and pedagogue answer! I'm liking the middle solution especially! I'm going to test it and get back to you!